# Can we add another custom option in the Insert Link option - SharePoint List (Multiple lines of Text)

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, custom-list, custom-actions, multiple-lines-of-text

Can we **add another custom option below the "From SharePoint and From Address"** or some where in this INSERT ribbon like Embed Code?
Any help?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use [SharePoint Add-ins](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/sp-add-ins/sharepoint-add-ins) to customize and extend the SharePoint server ribbon.

More information for your reference:

https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/12/02/customizing-sharepoint-ribbon/

https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/adding-custom-action-to-the-ribbon-of-view-in-sharepoint-list-library/